# Does `COUNT` discard duplicates?

Tags: dbms

My professor taught me this SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(length) FROM product
```

will return `2` with the following dataset:

```
product
|id | length | code |
|-------------------|
| 1 |    11  | X00  |
| 2 |    11  | C02  |
| 3 |    40  | A31  |
```

She justified it by saying that `COUNT` doesn't count duplicates. I disagreed. After trying a lot of DBMS, I've never found one that has this behaviour. Does such an DBMS exist?

Comment: Since the slides talk about ANSi SQL your professor is wrong, even in the 1992 standard (see page 125 here http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) lists the various behaviors for count with and without DISTINCT. You might want to visit the library tonged an updated version (which includes more options like ALL/OVER)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`COUNT` does count duplicates in all DBMS I'm aware of, but.

> Is there any reason for a professor to teach this behaviour

Yes, there is a reason. In the original relational theory (that underlies all modern relational DBMSes) *relation* is a *set* in mathematical sense of this word. That means that no relation can contain duplicates at all, including all transitional relations, not just your “tables”.

Following this principle you may say that `SELECT length FROM product` already contains only two rows, hence corresponding `COUNT` returns `2`, not `3`.

---

For example, in [Rel](https://reldb.org/c/) DBMS, using the relation given in the question and [Tutorial D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(data_language_specification)) syntax:

```
SUMMARIZE product {length} BY {}: {c := COUNT()}
```

gives:

[image: Rel result]

Comment: Since we had relational theory courses with this professor later this year, I think this is the correct answer. Anyway, I'll ask my professor for more information.

Comment: The teacher maybe was talking about DBMSs in general, not only about SQL DBMSs. As the edit shows, there are implementations of the relational model (eg Rel), where `COUNT` behaves differently than SQL implementations.

Answer (score 46):

Either your professor made a mistake or you misunderstood what she said. In the context of relational DBMSes, as implemented by various vendors, the aggregate function `COUNT(<expression>)` returns the number of non-NULL values of `<expression>` in the result set (or a group).

There is a special case of `COUNT(*)`, which returns the number of *rows* in the result set or group, not the number of values of anything. This is equivalent to `COUNT(<constant expression>)`, such as `COUNT(1)`.

Many databases support `COUNT(DISTINCT <expression>)`, which *will* return the number of unique values of `<expression>`.

Answer (score 14):

If your professor is talking about SQL, the statement is wrong. `COUNT(x)` will return the number of rows where x `IS NOT NULL` including duplicates. `COUNT(*) or COUNT([constant])` is a special case that will count the rows, even those where every column is `NULL`. However, duplicates are always counted, unless you specify `COUNT(distinct x)`. Example:

```
with t(x,y) as ( values (null,null),(null,1),(1,null),(1,1) )

select count(*) from t
4

select count(1) from t
4

select count(distinct 1) from t
1

select count(x) from t
2

select count(distinct x) from t
1
```

`COUNT(distinct *)` is invalid AFAIK.

As a side note, NULL introduces some unintuitive behaviour. As an example:

```
SELECT SUM(x) + SUM(y),  SUM(x + y) FROM T
4, 2
```

i.e:

```
SUM(x)+SUM(y) <> SUM(x+y)
```

If he/she is talking about a relational system as described by, for example, the book [Databases, Types, and the Relational Model: The Third Manifesto](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Databases-Types-Relational-Model-C-J/dp/0321399420/sr=1-2/qid=1169757255/ref=sr_1_2/203-3128636-8071105?ie=UTF8&s=books) by C. J. Date and Hugh Darwen - it would be a correct statement.

Say that we have the relation:

```json
STUDENTS = Relation(["StudentId", "Name"]
                    , [{"StudentId":'S1', "Name":'Anne'},
                       {"StudentId":'S2', "Name":'Anne'},
                       {"StudentId":'S3', "Name":'Cindy'},
                     ])
```

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM STUDENTS
```

corresponds to:

```
COUNT(STUDENTS.project(['Name']))
```

i.e.

```json
COUNT( Relation(["Name"]
               , [{"Name":'Anne'},
                  {"Name":'Cindy'},
                ]) )
```

which would return **2**.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it works in MS SQL Server

> COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL
>   values and duplicates.
>
> COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and
>   returns the number of nonnull values.
>
> COUNT(DISTINCT expression) evaluates expression for each row in a
>   group and returns the number of unique, nonnull values.

Answer (score 2):

If the table had looked like this,

```
|   product         |
|id | length | code |
|-------------------|
| 1 |    11  | X00  |
| 2 |    11  | C02  |
| 3 |  null  | A31  |
```

you could expect the query to return 2, at least in Oracle DB, as nulls are not counted. Duplicates are however counted just fine.

Answer (score -7):

maybe she mean in conjunction with unique, But Count does COUNT DUPLICATES.
There are some teachers who do not know their stuff, no worries just inform your classmates/friends so that when they go on to higher db and real life they wont forget, better yet send an anonymous message to your teacher asking her that they did not understand some of the sql functions and want a demonstration, have your teacher come up with a way for the class to suggest what to insert include duplicates (do not have the data be large) and when she uses the function count, you got her. Some people will pickup on it, Also when she says other databases, have your friend ask her which ones, then double snare her and say you tried all those databases and they don't work like she said and that count picks up duplicates.

Comment: I'm not sure I would set out to deliberately antagonize the teacher. With some, it might be entirely adequate to just meet with them personally and ask about it, with you counter-example ready (just to show that you've got a reason to be asking). Still, the basics of the approach are valid; up to the OP the specific direction to use.